# Average velocity question?

Tags: calculus, average

I usually know how to do these but this one gives me trouble.

If a ball is thrown into the air with a velocity of 46 ft/s, its height in feet t seconds later is given by $y = 46t − 16t_{2}$.

(a) Find the average velocity for the time period beginning when t = 2 and lasting for each of the following.
      .5 seconds ______
      .1 seconds ______
      .05 seconds _______
      .01 seconds ______

(b) Estimate the instantaneous velocity when $t = 2$.

_______ ft/s

Comment: Such questions are all the same and have all been asked and answered before. Just search.

Comment: If you ever need to ask future questions here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying numbers, variables, etc.

Comment: Also please note this is not a site where you can simply put down a questions and expect us to do all the work for you. Please show how you attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: Just how is this problem giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

You have height $h$ as a function of time $h=f(t)$

The rate of change of height is the velocity so take the derivative of height with respect to time to get a function for velocity $v$.

To get the average of $v$ from time $t=2$ to a final time $t=T$ use the integral

$\frac{1}{T-2}\int_{2}^{T}v dt$